# glewInit() bug with Dynamically generated objects?

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I'm making a Connect4 game using freeglut and glew. This is how my game looks. The circles (white/red/blue) were the only objects rendered at every single call back of the display() function.

```
Circle * ChessPiece = new Circle(0.08f);
```

[image]

Every thing worked fine, except that if I let the app sit for about 2 minutes, it crashed with the following error message:

[image]

The way I resolved this issue was to add these 2 lines right above glGenVertexArrays()

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

glewInit();

This worked. However, it resulted in a performance hit (since glewInit() was called every single time a circle was rendered, at every display() call back).

I tried to put glewExperimental and glewInit() inside the display() call-back function hoping to improve the performance, but the app still crashed after 2 minutes of running.

Another work-around was to pre-render all the circles at the very beginning, and then just change the color as the game progresses. This worked also. However, I would prefer to dynamically generate circles during the game progress, not at the beginning of the game.

So, my question is:

Is this a GLEW bug? or is this my code problem? The reason why I'm thinking its' a glew bug was because when I added glewExperimental and glewInit() right before glGenVertexArrays(), the game no longer crashed. The only downside was the massive performance hit.

Putting glewExperimental and glewInit() in the main() function or in the display() call-back function didn't work either. The app would compile and run fine for the first 2 minutes before it crashed.

If it's a GLEW bug, how do I get around this issue? (without having to pre-render the circles at the beginning of the game).

Code snipet for drawing the circle:

```
void Circle::draw(float x, float y, float z)
{
    //Codes to generate circle vertices 

    //These stop the app from crashing after 2 minutes, but I don't want to use them
    //glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    //glewInit();

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray_Circle);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArray_Circle);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer_Circle);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer_Circle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (sizeof(Circle_vertices)/sizeof(float))*sizeof(GLfloat), Circle_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

   //Draw circle
   glBindVertexArray(vertexArray_Circle);
   glVertexAttrib3f((GLuint)1, RED, GREEN, BLUE);
   glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, index/3);

   glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

Comment: Are you actually generating vertex arrays every frame? Do you delete them again?

Comment: You should use a debugger and find where the exception is coming from, without that you can only guess.

Comment: I'm generating the arrays at every single frame (sorry, I'm an OpenGL noob here). I have edited my post to put in the code to generate the circle.

Comment: Generate the array once. Render with it many times.

Comment: Also, why are you calling glewInit every round? That should only be called once.

Comment: I did that because that was the only way (that I knew) that could stop my app from crashing after 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice to see the actual code, rather than just a screen-shot of it, but it looks like you're generating a new vertex array every time you draw, and it fails just after this...

I suspect that you're not actually deleting those vertex arrays, and given long enough, you're running out of resources and the call fails. Without checking for errors, you end up crashing.

Really you should not regenerate the array unless necessary, and if it is, make sure you delete the old one.

Comment: Thank you. That was probably the problem - I forgot to delete the vertex arrays. I'll try that. I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Yep! That was it! I did not delete the vertex array and that was the culprit of the crash. After deleting the vertex array and the vertex buffer, the app no longer crashed. Thank you very much. What I'm wondering was that what could have glewInit() did to prevent the app from crashing? Before deleting the vertex arrays like you suggested, I called glewInit() every time the vertices were created, and it stopped the app from crashing. So, glewInit() must have done something. Interesting... Thanks again, every one.

Comment: @TATN: Stop creating and destroying them. There's no point in that; just use them again. Objects should not be ephemeral.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I originally wrote this game as a hobby console-based game (to practice coding the AI algorithm). When it was done, I decided to add the GUI with OpenGL. Since I were too lazy :) to redesign the flow logic of the game, I wrote the OpenGL code closely resemble to the console-based codes for the GUI. As a result, I ended up creating the circles at every single display() call-back. Bad practice, I know. I'll keep your advice in mind for my next OpenGL hobby project. Thank you for your input.